# Using Terminal I want to copy some files

Tags: command-line, clipboard

Assuming I'm not in my home directory, I want to copy all the files starting with "a" from my home directory to my current directory.

I've tried `cp ~ a* .` and different variations of that but it hasn't worked at all. 
Thank you.

Edit: *Thank you again

Comment: Super-fast answers you've received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`cp -r ~/a* <path-to-end-directory>`

Your current directory is `.`, the directory above you is `..`
.

So the *exact* command you'd want is `cp -r ~/a* .`

Answer (score 3):

`cp ~/a* .` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be `cp ~/a* .`